# QGIS Crashing in Ubuntu / 'Save As' browsing

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

When trying to create a new shapefile in QGIS on Ubuntu, I get a crash whenever I browse to a folder to save the file.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a problem with other Ubuntu software as well.

Using Scribus, a similar problem was occurring.

Sure enough, their developers tracked it down to a problem with the QT library (see below).

Having this issue resolved, I immediately tried to open QGIS and create a new shapefile. The browse dialogue that "create new shapefile" uses - which for some reason is a different system dialogue box than usual - worked just fine!

My conclusion is the QT bug was affecting QGIS as it was Scribus!

http://forums.scribus.net/index.php/topic,638.0.html

This bug in scribus-1.4.1/ubuntu-12.04 is written up here ..
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scribus/+bug/973332
this may be resolved by uninstalling the qt-at-spi package
through Synaptic Package Manager.
or
sudo apt-get remove qt-ap-spi
This bug is reported as fixed in Qt 4.8.2
However in my ubuntu 12.04 I do not experience any such crashes and
my qt-at-spi package   accessibility plugin for qt
reports latest available version 0.2.0+git20120411-0ubuntu1